Get Angular Component height from Grid Layout
I'm trying to retrieve a component's height within itself (using ElementRef), which is located within a css grid layout. Background is the component renders images via picture-tag and depending on the grid layout the component might be rather small, but it would still render images dedicated to a large viewport. So I want to check the component's actual dimensions and dictate whatever image size I allow for this very instance.
EDIT:
the thing is that the grid layout is styled in a way, that all images are cropped if necessary. So if you have a grid element that has a column like shape, the source image must stay rather big, but lots of its content left and right will be cut off.  I'm trying to target the grid elements that still retain  the same proportions of the image. this is where I need to restrict large srcsets from being rendered.
The Problem is that even for the Lifecycle Hook "AfterViewInit" I still get height values of "0" for "this.elRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight".
(btw. For some reason the offsetWidth is returned properly in time, but not the height.)
Only "AfterViewChecked" would finally give me the final height that I can work with, but that lifecycle hook is called countless times, which would lead to all the repeated iterations of the same logic building the component.
This what I tried and probably would work, but is no option due to the repeated iterations.
class ImageComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  heightSubject = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  public height$: Observable<number> = this.heightSubject.asObservable();
  constructor(public component: CmsComponentData<CmsComponent>, elRef: ElementRef){}
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.heightSubject.next(this.elRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  }

  compData$: Observable<BannerData> = combineLatest([this.component.data$, this.height$]).pipe(
    map(([data, height] : [CmsBannerComponent, number]) => {
      if(height < 500){
        return data.smallImage;
      }
      return data.bigImage;
    });
}

Is there a proper way to reliably get a component's dimensions in such cases?
Best Regards

Is it really necessery to check the height of the grid element? Can't image resize itself to fit the available space? If it is really requirder how about using some directives that you would add on the grid element container and using IntersectionApi? As of why width is of correct value is probably because of styles. At the beginning the element is empty but still take a whole width available and the inner element that is picture is not created yet.

the thing is that the grid layout is styled in a way, that all images are cropped if necessary. So if you have a grid element that has a column like shape, the source image must stay rather big, but lots of its content left and right will be cut off.  I'm trying to target the grid elements that still retain  the same proportions of the image. this is where I need to restrict large srcsets from being rendered.

Can you add stackblitz example of your issue? I may be misunderstanding something but to me it still sounds like what you want can be achieved purely with css.

I'll try to setup an example, but the thing is that I'm not looking how things look from a UI perspective, but what kind of data is requested. I dont want large images requested if their container is way smaller than the srcset defined for the current viewport
